# sql select date range next year issue

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, date-range

I'm trying to create a select statement adding days to the CURDATE, using the below code:

```
      SELECT
                po.factory,
                po_item.po,
                po_item.style,
                po_item.style_name,
                po_item.customer_style,
                po_item.colors,
                po_item.material,
                po_item.pairs,
                po.sef,
                po.client,
                ROUND(((po_item.pairs)/12)) as total_ctn,
                style.shoe_dimension,
                factory.official_name,
            DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+10, '%m/%d/%y') as FROMTHIS,
            DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+17, '%m/%d/%y') as TOTHIS,
            CASE WHEN 
                po.rlsd is not null THEN po.rlsd ELSE po.lsd END AS date
            FROM 
                po_item
                inner join po on 
                    po_item.po = po.po
                inner join factory on 
                    po.factory = factory.id
                      inner join style on po_item.style = style.style
                      inner join client on po.client = client.id
                      inner join divisions on client.division = divisions.id
            WHERE
                divisions.group_division_id = '19'
                AND po.ref is null 
                AND po.status != 'C'
            ORDER BY 
                po.cls DESC
```

This is how is the return:

[image]

```
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+10, '%m/%d/%y') as FROMTHIS,
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+17, '%m/%d/%y') as TOTHIS,
```

are both returning {null}, because this is next year date, since CURDATE(today) which is 2017/12/10 +12 should be 2018/01/01 but return as {null}

Does anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks

And then I would like to use both on the where statement, like:

```
      SELECT
                po.factory,
                po_item.po,
                po_item.style,
                po_item.style_name,
                po_item.customer_style,
                po_item.colors,
                po_item.material,
                po_item.pairs,
                po.sef,
                po.client,
                ROUND(((po_item.pairs)/12)) as total_ctn,
                style.shoe_dimension,
                factory.official_name,
                DATE_FORMAT(po.cls, '%m/%d/%y') AS date_cls,
                DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%y') as date_today,
                DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+10, '%m/%d/%y') as audit,
            DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 12 DAY), '%m/%d/%y') AS FROMTHIS,
            DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 17 DAY), '%m/%d/%y') AS TOTHIS,
            CASE WHEN 
                po.rlsd is not null THEN po.rlsd ELSE po.lsd END AS date
            FROM 
                po_item
                inner join po on 
                    po_item.po = po.po
                inner join factory on 
                    po.factory = factory.id
                      inner join style on po_item.style = style.style
                      inner join client on po.client = client.id
                      inner join divisions on client.division = divisions.id
            WHERE
                po.cls BETWEEN `FROMTHIS` AND `TOTHIS`
                AND divisions.group_division_id = '19'
                AND po.ref is null 
                AND po.status != 'C'
            ORDER BY 
                po.po,
                po.cls DESC
```

but is not working

Comment: Is it sql-server or MySql

Comment: sorry, MySql @Kapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY), '%m/%d/%y') AS FROMTHIS
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 17 DAY), '%m/%d/%y') AS TOTHIS
```

Comment: Hi, it works. Please help me one more time, I just update my question

Comment: Store it in one variable and then try to use it

Comment: How is the better way to do it? and then use it on the where clause?

Comment: If "po.cls" have the datatype as DateTime then you can achieve by this way:

 SET @FROMDATE = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
 SET @ToDATE = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);

 SELECT * FROM po WHERE `po.cls` BETWEEN @FROMDATE  AND @ToDATE;